Groovy multiline variable substitution error in Jenkins job
I have a jenkins job stage where I define a shell command as a multiline string, depending upon the input passed the variables have to be substituted and the command is executed in the jenkins job stage.
Code sample
def command = """
python3 test.py --key1=$value1 \
--key2=${value2}01-test-env \
--key3=list:${value3}
"""
def exitCode = sh(script: command, returnStatus: true)

I am getting errors for the unexpected character errors and bad substitution, tried to use the escape delimiters and dollar slashy string.

What is the error message? How are the variables defined?

Variables are defined from the input as well as some env variables set based on the conditional check, I use ${params.Variable} and ${env.Variable} in the command.

Does your command work correctly if you hard code in the values instead of using variables?

What happens if you check the variables outside of your multi-line function? Try both echo $value1 and sh """ echo $value1"""

Please edit the question and add the actual error message from the log.

def command = """
python3 test.py --key1=$value1 \  <<<< these are a problem
--key2=${value2}01-test-env \
--key3=list:${value3}
"""

So you have to remember we're in Groovy when writing shell code, and the \ character is used for escape sequences in strings.  So Groovy interprets a single \ in a String as an escape sequence that is missing a letter after it like \n or \t.  But, you want a single \ in the string that is needed by the underlying shell command.  Therefore swap your \ for its escape sequence \\.  So your code should be:
def command = """
python3 test.py --key1=$value1 \\
--key2=${value2}01-test-env \\
--key3=list:${value3}
"""

That should fix it.
